# Checking hashed password on login

Tags: php, mysql

Next thing bothers me: hashing password makes them practically irreversible. So if I store password in database with any of hash alghorytms, on next login, how will I check is the password in database? Or simplier I wonder how to decrypt hashed password when logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hash the password the user provides using the same algorithm and compare it against the stored one.

In PHP 5.5, there are new functions [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify) built in for this that use the industy-standard bcrypt algorithm. In PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.3 (v 5.3.7+), the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library provides the same functions.

Comment: Adding to his @ceejayoz's point, the point of hashing a password is intended to not be able to reverse it. When you hash two values that are the same, you will get the same result, and so that's how you would compare if a password matches; by checking if a hashed input matches the stored hashed version in a database, we obscure anyone, including admin or hackers alike from viewing stored user passwords.